# BotFramework , Not Receiving Response To First Message

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm using Microsoft BotFramework and have created one simple Bot.
Flow is something like,
User Says Hi -> Bot responds with Greeting what user can ask
User Asks relevant Question -> Bot Responds with Answer and Possible Next Question and then Again flow continues with User Asking Question

on Local Emulator everything works fine. However when I use published API App it doesn't show response to Users "Hi" , if user asks any other relevant question everything works fine.

Also on bot page it does not show any errors also so it is not error.

I also added try catch block and sent error as message that also did not show any message , again pointing towards no error.

i tried debug with ngrok and there also it complets whole block without going into catch or any unexpected path.

So I'm lost with where it can go wrong!!!

Any pointers will be useful.

Thanks,
Dilkush

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the bot in Azure? If so, make sure you have "AlwaysOn" enabled; otherwise the web app will be unloaded if it's idle for a period of time. Check [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1343) for a similar problem.

> **Always On**. By default, web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable Always On to keep the app loaded all the time. If your app runs continuous web jobs, you should enable Always On, or the web jobs may not run reliably.

You can read more about the web sites configuration [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/).